# Serving an "index.html" file in public/ when using MeteorJS and Iron Router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to serve a static HTML file from MeteorJS's public folder (as is possible with Rails and Express). The reason I'm doing this is because I have one template for the dynamic "admin" part of my webapp and another for the sales-y "frontend" part of the app.

I don't want this file to be wrapped in a Meteor template as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510745/meteor-js-public-folder-not-serving-html-file) as it will automatically bring in the minified CSS, etc... that the dynamic pages use.

Is there a way I can setup the public folder (and all its subfolders) so that it serves index.html? This way http://app.com/ will load public/index.html?

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`private` folder](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) instead and then use [`Assets.getText`](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets_getText) to load the contents of the file, then serve it with a server-side router from iron-router.

So off the top of my head the code would look something like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Router.map(function() {
    this.route('serverRoute', {
      path: '/',
      where: 'server',
      action: function() {
        var contents = Assets.getText('index.html');
        this.response.end(contents);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `this.response.end(contents);` to end the connection.

Comment: Hi Rahul, this is working great but not for server generated files. For example, in the /private folder, there are test1.html and test2.html. When I mup deploy to Digital Ocean server, test1.html and test2.html are working great! However, when I generated test3.html into the same folder as test1.html and test2.html, it just showed "Server error." How to make test3.html working? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to help without seeing your code. Please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I put in `bootstrap.js`

```
Router.route('/', {
  where: 'server'
}).get(function() {
  var contents;
  contents = Assets.getText('index.html');
  return this.response.end(contents);
});
```