# Serving server generated static files when using Meteor and Digital Ocean

Tags: meteor, static-files, meteor-up

I want to serve a static file from MeteorJS's private folder. 
I had made it working for uploaded static files but not yet for server generated files.

```
Router.route('/:etrs', {
  name: 'serverRoute',
  where: 'server',
  action: function() {
    var contents = Assets.getText(this.params.etrs);
    this.response.end(contents);
  }
});
```

For example, in the /private folder, there are test1.html and test2.html. When I mup deploy to Digital Ocean server, test1.html and test2.html are working great! However, when I generated test3.html into the same folder as test1.html and test2.html, it just showed "Server error." How to make test3.html working? Thanks!

Reference: [Serving an “index.html” file in public/ when using MeteorJS and Iron Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871590/serving-an-index-html-file-in-public-when-using-meteorjs-and-iron-router/23871890#comment44112828_23871890)

Comment: How are you generating that third file? Do you know on what path its living? If so, you can use `fs.readFileSync` instead of `Assets.getText`.

Comment: The files generated (server) through fs.outputFile(). Yes, I know the path. After changing to fs.readFileSync(), still same issue, i.e. "Server error." :(

Comment: Do you have any further details on this error? like stack trace or more descriptive error message? Can you access the server logs?

Comment: From what I understand, when you build your application, everything inside the `private`, `public` directories get passed into the build directory. So you cannot generate a `test3.html` into the `private` directory, because it doesn't exists when the application is built and running. You may need to save your file somewhere else. This is all speculation from my limited understanding, I'll let the more experienced folks give you an answer. Please feel free to correct me also.